# Can't start Windows 7 after hard shutdown

Tags: windows-7, boot, laptop, memory, battery

Something funny happened. I develop artificial intelligence software on my Dell Inspiron 17R, so I frequently have to deal with very large datasets in Java. Here we go.

1. Last night, I was performing some typical office-ish tasks (I'm a student), so I was using 1-2 of my 8GB RAM.
2. I ran an AI test, which ramped up CPU to ~100% and RAM was pretty big until I could no longer track it from Process Explorer, because ...
3. My computer froze, presumably from using up all the memory.
4. My screen flicked out of Aero for a moment --- normally this is because Battery Care wants to save power on battery mode, but I was on AC the entire time.
5. I gave my system a minute or so to "wake up," then ...
6. I gave it the hug of death to shut down, and proceeded to restart.
7. Startup failed, auto-restart, and it wants to enter Startup Repair.
8. Some more helplessness, and then my dad recommended that I disconnect AC and battery and press the power button for a while.
9. Restart.
10. Chose normal boot.
11. Windows logo animation.
12. BSOD and auto-restart.
13. User gave up and powered computer mid-BIOS.

**How can I get my computer working again? Apparently Startup Repair isn't any good.**

**Do I dare attempt more Startup Repair, etc. without backing up my HD?**

Comment: Your AI escaped, taking important Windows files with it to prevent you discovering that the source code is now gone. Thanks for starting Skynet.

Comment: @MichaelFrank I never thought machines would beat humans already ---- at least, though given how amazing Java is, it's not a big surprise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

BSOD and auto-restarts? It seems to me a RAM problem.
You could try replacing your RAM if you have a memory bank available or if your 8GB are split in two banks you can try to restart with only one bank at a time to identify the broken one.

If your RAM banks are ok and the problem is of software nature you could try with [Yumi](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/yumi-multiboot-usb-creator/) (boot USB creator) and Boot Repair Disk to fix Windows startup problems.

Comment: But could go explain why this RAM problem was absent before?

Comment: A RAM problem is absent until it appears ;) Have you discovered anything?

Comment: Okay. Memtestx86+ passed. Fedora, Ubuntu, Tails, and Windows 7 rescue disc all freeze somewhere in boot. At least the latter was able to load the mouse driver.

Comment: Can you link to Boot Repair Disk?

Comment: Simon if you follow the link to Yumi and install it you'll find a list of available ISO images to download. Otherwise you can find BRD here: http://sourceforge.net/projects/boot-repair-cd/  If I were in you I would try to extract one RAM slot at a time and boot. If all these OS froze at startup it must be an hardware problem...